# How to specific application to my Windows search in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I am using windows 8. When I install some application and search for it using the new Start menu it doesnt appear to show. This is very frustrating since I have to manually go to the location in order to run the program. Is there any way to add a program to the windows start menu?

Comment: I suggest you upgrade to Windows 8.1 this problem sort if solves itself

Comment: Is there any other program I can use instead. I dont want to upgrade to 8.1 just for this

Comment: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-to-pin-items-to-51be533c

Comment: @Sab there are more reasons you should upgrade.  Microsoft doesn't plan on supporting windows 8.0 for very long